# Database Transaction Using OrientDB Guice Plugin

Tags: java, guice, orientdb

I am new to Guice Plugin.

Can anyone provide me with sample code for database transaction using orientDB guice plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this plugin?

https://github.com/xvik/guice-persist-orient

Should be documented

Comment: I am using the same plugin, given on that link.